# How to combine within same variable?

Tags: javascript

Assuming I had this function below:

```js
function highlightRed() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var grid = $("#grid1").data("kendoGrid");
        var data = grid.dataSource.view();

        $.each(data, function (i, row) {
            var element = $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"] ');
            if (row.active == "n") {
                $(element).css("background-color", "#F99AA1"); 
            }
        });
    }, 10);
}
```

In this function I already assign  `var grid = $("#grid1").data("kendoGrid");` but now I have more than one gridID.

```
var grid = $("#grid1").data("kendoGrid"); 
var grid = $("#grid2").data("kendoGrid"); 
var grid = $("#grid3").data("kendoGrid"); 
var grid = $("#grid4").data("kendoGrid");
```

How do I combine it and used same variable `grid` name in the same function? Instead me create another function.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is it that you are asking about? Do you want to execute that piece of code (in setTimeout) for every grid you list here? If so, create a function where you can pass the grid-object and call if for each grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the dynamic number as argument to your function:

```
function highlightRed(num) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var grid = $("#grid" + num).data("kendoGrid");
        var data = grid.dataSource.view();

        $.each(data, function (i, row) {
            var element = $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"] ');
            if (row.active == "n") {
                $(element).css("background-color", "#F99AA1"); 
            }
        });
    }, 10);
}
```

And call the function like:

```
highlightRed(1);
highlightRed(2);
highlightRed(3);
highlightRed(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `forEach` loop to run the same code on a list of similar things.

```
var grids = [ $("#grid1"), $("#grid2"), $("#grid3"), $("#grid4") ]
grids.forEach(function(grid) {
    var data = grid.dataSource.view();
    // .. etc ..
})
```

[Array forEach docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `[id^=grid]` CSS selector to select all elements starting with "grid":

```
function highlightRed() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var grid = $("[id^=grid]").data("kendoGrid");
    var data = grid.dataSource.view();
    $.each(data, function (i, row) {
      var element = $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"] '); 
        if (row.active == "n") {
          $(element).css("background-color", "#F99AA1");
        }
      });
    }, 10);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not combine objects in a variable (without processing)

if you have html string and want to concatenate that html to existing one, you can use + operator for that purpose.

var grid = '';
grid += 'your loop processed string value'.

I hope this is what you asked for